# Where to find documentation on the `fun` argument in `geom_line`?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm going through the Udacity lessons on R, and one of the exercises has me write this code in order to draw a scatter plot and overlay a "mean" line and three "quartile" lines.

```
ggplot(aes(x = age, y = friend_count), data = pf) + 
  xlim(13, 90) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.05, position  = position_jitter(h = 0), color = 'orange') +
  coord_trans(y = 'sqrt') +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = mean) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = 0.1), color = 'blue', linetype = 2) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = 0.5), color = 'blue', linetype = 2) +
  geom_line(stat = 'summary', fun.y = quantile, fun.args = list(probs = 0.9), color = 'blue', linetype = 2)
```

I want to see the documentation for the `fun` parameter inside of `geom_line`, so I looked at the documentation for `geom_line` (both in R Studio and online), and the `geom_line` function is shown as

```
geom_line(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "identity", position = "identity", 
na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE, ...)
```

I don't see the `fun` parameter anywhere.  So my question is: if I didn't already about the `fun` parameter from the Udacity lesson, how would I know about it from looking at the documentation and what do I look to get more information about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short version:**

In `?stat_summary` we find the `fun.y` argument.

**How to arrive there:**

First check **Arguments** in `?geom_line`. There we find the 'ellipsis argument' `...`:

> `...`  other arguments passed on to `layer`.

Then follow the link to `?layer`:

> Usually layers are created using `geom_*` or `stat_*`

In your case, you used the wrapper `geom_line` (instead of `layer(geom = "line",`) together with `stat = "summary"`. The latter thus leads us to `stat_summary`.

And finally, in `?stat_summary` we find the `fun.y` argument.

Comment: @BenRubin "They may also be parameters to the paired geom/stat": the `fun.y` arguments are for `stat_summary`, you will find them documented there.